# Issue when upgrading tfstate terraform version

Tags: terraform, upgrade

I'm running into this issue: I have a tfstate file with version 0.12, and I want to upgrade it to 0.13. The code is using modules, and one of the modules got changed in a way that will make terraform plan fail for current code. Since running the code will fail, I'm unable to upgrade it to new version. I cannot change the module to previous state. What would be the best solution to get past this issue?

Comment: What error do you get? Do you get it on `init` or `plan`?

Comment: Since you haven't shared any details about what errors you encountered it's hard to give any sort of specific answer, but you might find some help in [the Terraform v0.13 Upgrade Guide](https://www.terraform.io/upgrade-guides/0-13.html). If you don't see something matching the problem you are having in there, please edit your question to describe what problem you encountered, including the full error messages you saw and any configuration portions that the error messages are referring to.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `terraform init -upgrade`

Comment: nope didn't work, tfstate terraform version is still at 0.12

Comment: Did you download latest terraform version?